# What does uint32_t stand for?

Tags: c, naming-conventions, language-design

I expect `uint32` means "unsigned 32-bit integer".

What does the `t` stand for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The suffix `_t`denotes a **type name**. For example, `size_t` is the type for size.

Another popular line of thought regards it as a convention for naming **type definitions**.

Answer (score 11):

uint32_**t** = unsigned integer 32-bit **type**.